# Which OS is best if I want to play around with exploits?

Tags: security, operating-systems

I am reading the book: Hacking: The Art of Exploitation, and the author has provided examples of buffer overflow attacks and nop-sled exploits.

I somehow can’t run these examples on my MacOS/Linux as they seem to have patched these vulnerabilities.

Is there an Operating System which is so basic when it comes to security, that I can play around with these exploits?

Comment: You should be able to run these on Linux, you just need an exploitable program. Any good hacking challenge should include some buggy programs for you to hack :) Notice you are learning the techniques, not how they apply to an OS - necessarily, because if the OS had them long enough for them to get into a book, the OS is crap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a really good book that I use with my students!

The book comes with a CD that has an image that you can run in Oracle VirtualBox.  You'll also find all of the book examples preloaded there, and the text outputs in the book itself are from that system.  IIRC, it's a dated system from the early 90's with all sorts of protections disabled.

Obviously, "Hacking: The Art of Exploitation" is not meant to show you anything especially modern, but instead it guides you through hands-on exploits and teaches foundational ideas about how hacking really works.  It's a wild ride - enjoy it!